# Get line from file at specified byte offset

Tags: python, perl, parsing, unix

I have a file with a bunch of lines. I have a list of the bytes offsets corresponding with the start of each line. I want each line that corresponds with the byte offset. Is there a way to do this in unix, perl or python? I have to do this at a much larger scale than described.

File:

```
abcd
bcde
cdef
```

Byte Offsets:

```
0
10
```

Desired Output:

```
abcd
cdef
```

Comment: +1 not only to counter the drive-by downvotes. This is clearly a programming problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:    
    for offset in offsets:
        f.seek(offset)
        print(f.readline())
```

References:

- [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)
- [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)
- [seek](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek)
- [readline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with:

    f = open(filename, 'r')
    offsets = [0,10]
    for offset in offsets:
            f.seek(offset)
            print f.readline().strip()

Answer (score 4):

Quickie perl:

```
my @offsets = ( 0, 10 );

open (my $data, '<', 'file.txt') || die "Can't open input: $!\n";

foreach my $offset (@offsets) 
{
    seek( $data, $offset, 0 );
    my $line = <$data>;
    print $line;
}

close $data;
```

Comment: +1, but strongly recommend `open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt'` instead of using a bare filehandle.

Answer (score 1):

`seek()` to the required byte position, then read. This should be easy from Python and Perl, and doable from shell script (I'm thinking `dd`).

Comment: `tail -c +$OFFSET` to seek, then `head -n 1` to get only the first line.

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. This is slightly painful so I would go for a scripting language. You could even do it in Awk. Reading and discarding unwanted lines could even be faster than repeatedly seeking if the desired lines are not very sparsely distributed.

Comment: You can do it in `sh`. I think it's something like `tail -c +$2 $1 | head -n 1` in a shell script, and saying `cat byte-offsets.file | xargs -n 1 yourscript.sh lines.file`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
def get_lines_by_offset(filename, *offsets):
    with open(filename, "r") as fp:
        results = []
        for offset in offsets:
            fp.seek(offset)
            results.append(fp.readline().strip())
    return results
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ended up with (thanks to unutbu)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
f = open(file_name, 'r')
offsets = [0,10]
for offset in offsets:
    f.seek(offset)
    print f.readline().strip()
```